# How to make plain array from nested?

Tags: javascript

Here is an array:

```
let arr = [{key: 1, value: "A", children: [{key: 2, value: "B"}]}]
```

I tried to make the plain list with the sequance number of elements:

```
let list = [{key: 1, value: "A", "num": 1}, {key: 2, value: "B", "num": "1.1"}]
```

My realization is:

```
  private productsWithNumber(products: any[]) {
    const arr = [];
    products.forEach((p, index: number) => {
      p['num'] = index + 1;
      if (p?.children) {
        p.children.forEach((element, index) => {
          element['num'] = `${p['num']}.${index + 1}.`;
          arr.push(element);
        });
      }
      arr.push(p);
    });

    return arr;
  }
```

As result I got wrong ordre of elements. How to simplify it?

Comment: Javascript has a function that can sort arrays.  Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: What are you passing in as `products`? What order are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looping through all items, then loop through the children, *add the children*, and just *then add the parent*.

You can simply add the parent first to get the correct order:

```js
  private productsWithNumber(products: any[]) {
    const arr = [];
    products.forEach((p, index: number) => {
      p['num'] = index + 1;
      arr.push(p); // <-- moved this line up
      if (p?.children) {
        p.children.forEach((element, index) => {
          element['num'] = `${p['num']}.${index + 1}.`;
          arr.push(element);
        });
      }
      
    });

    return arr;
  }
```

**Solution with arbitrary nesting:**

The current solution only works for 1 level nested `children`. If you want this to work for an arbitrary nesting level you can use *recursion*, for example like this:

```js
type ArrayItem = {
  children?: (ArrayItem | {})[]
}

  const flattenChildrenArray = <T extends ArrayItem>(arr: T[], level: string | null = null): Omit<T, "children">[] => {
    const tempArr: Omit<T, "children">[] = []
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
      const {children, ...rest} = item;
      
      const num = level ? `${level}.${index + 1}` : `${index + 1}`
      tempArr.push({
        ...rest,
        num,
      })
      if (children) {
        const flattenedChildren = flattenChildrenArray(children, num) as Omit<T, "children">[]
        tempArr.push(...flattenedChildren)
      }
    })
    return tempArr;
  }
```

[See a working example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0DeBrEBPAXBAjADQQBuUwAriHgEQCCNxAxgBYCWwAJjCAHZ5pMuCACZiZStQg0AQjQC%20AXXnEM2PCJUQ1wgMzN2XHvxQ68AFgMdufAWYgBWJc8UAoV2CwAHEBDpwoLABJMBAAW0RtVwgIVmtjAH48AAp-GECQ8IgAH215AEpkN3l3GKYAe14AZ0gAM2AoMFDeAGFDG140wMiAHgAVCBAAD2bOKr8A4NCwgD5k2Bg8PqLiUBIQYDwamDZeAHMciF4KYGBI49P8vAB5MLYwfuIaOKM%20GhmixBmomLLKmog0y8aRudwefSeLw670%20SCK0V%20CwAdLVyjAAKJQVjJZL3cLEXacYb5L4-X5-aqQVBQ4zEJH0ng1eSRPFhADcCPJnN%20FUpRwoESQaw2EASEAABgASVDC4DyJHSwnDCAAagI8nFEDwUtQSqGqvV4u5MSBaSRXgoVRYyVQxt%209KRjLAhDtMWOYRd5JiBTtbFqEGSNL4JNtXp5-zqDSafBAnDa8T4kXqjWa8denUmgfatP5YRJUHGt3uj2kQd4MLcYZN4WBcHNlutDuT0d4sbTHXydpK5J95J4YAoMF4gJraQ53vcvIBjJOkCQzdT2b4XSw8zgnYpVXKoCRwHKe2SM%20AYHyQA)

Comment: Problem is it modifies the initial array

Comment: Does my second solution do that as well? It should not because the object is spread.